# Integer to Date Format based on Business Month

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a Dataframe with a column `Date` of type `int`. I wanted to convert the `Date` of `Input_DF` to  last business day of particular month and store in new column as `Date2`. Is there any way possible to do this. Thanks in advance.

Input_DF:

```
Product Date    Country
A      200801   USA
C      201503   AUS
B      201002   UK
B      201704   FIN
C      200605   IRE
A      200805   CAN
```

Output_DF:

```
Product Date  Country  Date2
A      200801   USA     2008-01-31 
C      201503   AUS     2015-03-31
B      201002   UK      2010-02-26
B      201704   FIN     2017-04-28
C      200605   IRE     2006-05-31
A      200805   CAN     2008-05-30
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I assume you mean `pandas`, not `numpy` in your tags, right? Your dataframe looks like a `pandas` dataframe and not like a `numpy` array. Let me know if I'm wrong, I'll delete my answer

Comment: @sacul You are right! It was supposed to be numpy

Comment: @MooingRawr Thanks for your comment! I will make sure that I will post what I have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of built in datetime functionalities in `pandas`. Getting what you need is straightforward using [`offsets`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects). You first have to pass your date in the correct format to `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m') + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1)

>>> df
  Product    Date Country      Date2
0       A  200801     USA 2008-01-31
1       C  201503     AUS 2015-03-31
2       B  201002      UK 2010-02-26
3       B  201704     FIN 2017-04-28
4       C  200605     IRE 2006-05-31
5       A  200805     CAN 2008-05-30
```